# Django - Login POST se cuelga al hacer un HttpResponseRedirect (302)

Tags: python, django, login, django-views

Buenas me llamo Juan Manuel y les consulto por si les pasó alguna vez:

Tengo una pantalla login, común y corriente, cuando ejecuto el proceso de logueo (autentifica y registra el usuario bien) cuando tiene que redireccionar con un `HttpResponseRedirect()` el navegador queda cargando indefinidamente (queda en la pantalla de logueo cargando el `request`).

Por lo que pude ver en consola (abajo pongo la captura), luego del POST quiere redirigir con un HTTP 302 y queda ahí.

Estuve buscando sobre el tema pero no encuentro que puede ser, les paso algunas cosas que noté:

- No pasa siempre
- Chrome con modo desarrollo con cache desactivada no lo hace.
- Firefox no lo hace
- Con `reverse()` hace lo mismo (internamente llama a `HttpResponseRedirect()`)

Cuando queda colgado así, si presiono F5 para recargar, ejecuta bien la re dirección, pasa tanto en el servidor de desarrollo como en producción (servidor Apache).

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from .views import *
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include('tadese.urls')),    
    url(r'^login/$', login),
    url(r'^login_cuota/$', login_cuota),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG is False:   #if DEBUG is True it will be served automatically
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            url(r'^staticfiles/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    )
handler500 = volverHome
handler404 = volverHome
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login, authenticate, logout as django_logout
from django.shortcuts import *
from settings import *
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from tadese.models import Configuracion,Cuotas,Tributo,UserProfile
from tadese.utilidades import TRIBUTOS_LOGIN
from django.db.models import Q
from django.template.defaulttags import register
from django.conf import settings

def login(request):
    error = None
    LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL=settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL
    if request.method == 'GET':     
      if request.user.is_authenticated():    
        return volverHome(request)      
    try:
        sitio = Configuracion.objects.all().first()
    except Configuracion.DoesNotExist:
        sitio = None

    if sitio <> None:
      unico_padr = (sitio.ver_unico_padron == 'S')
      if sitio.mantenimiento == 1:
        return render_to_response('mantenimiento.html', {'dirMuni':MUNI_DIR,'sitio':sitio},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
      unico_padr = False
    if request.method == 'POST':

        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'],tributo=request.POST['tributo'])
        if user is not None:
          if user.is_active:
            django_login(request, user)

            if user.userprofile.tipoUsr==0:
                request.session["usuario"] = request.POST['username']
                if unico_padr:
                  try:
                        padr = Cuotas.objects.filter(padron=request.POST['username'],estado=0).order_by('-id_cuota').first()
                        if padr:
                          LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('ver_cuotas', kwargs={'idp':padr.id_padron})
                          return HttpResponseRedirect(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
                  except:
                        padr = None  
                else:
                  LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('padrones_responsable')
            return volverHome(request)
          else:
          ## invalid login
           error = u'Verifique que:\n. Los datos sean correctos.\n. Posea cuotas generadas en el sistema.'
        else:
          ## invalid login
           error = u'Verifique que:\n. Los datos sean correctos.\n. Posea cuotas generadas en el sistema.'
          #return direct_to_template(request, 'invalid_login.html')
    if error:
      messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,u'%s' % (error))
    tributos = Tributo.objects.filter()  
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'dirMuni':MUNI_DIR,'sitio':sitio,'tributos':tributos},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def logout(request):
    request.session.clear()
    django_logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(LOGIN_URL)

def volverHome(request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
      return HttpResponseRedirect(LOGIN_URL)    

    if request.user.userprofile.tipoUsr==0:
        LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('padrones_responsable')
    elif request.user.userprofile.tipoUsr==1:
        LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('padrones_estudio')
    else:
        LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('padrones_responsable')

    return HttpResponseRedirect(LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
```

Comment: prueba redireccionar con reverse_lazy de django.urls

Comment: Gracias por tu rta. pero el reverse_lazy no cambia nada